# Counting co-occurence in a list of list

Tags: python, list, counter

Using python, I define the following list of string lists

```
some_list = [['abc', 'aa', 'xdf'], ['def', 'asd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['ghi', 'edd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', ]]
```

What is the best way  to select and count the strings that appear in the same sublist than 'abc' ?  In this example I am looking for an output (dictionnary or list) such as:

```
('aa', 1), ('xdf', 1), ('xyz',2), (None, 1)
```

The `(None, 1)` would capture the cases where `'abc'` is the only string of the sublists).

Comment: How would you expect to return `(None, 1)` in your list of results when `None` does not appear in any of the lists? Would this be the case when `'abc'` is isolated inside it's own list?

Comment: Yes, the idea would be to also capture the number of times the 'abc' was the single element of a sublist.  (apologies,  the None was unclear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd count them all first and then handle the edge case separately:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(x for x in A if 'abc' in x))
c[None] = A.count(['abc'])
```

Comment: For long lists of short subllists, which solution is recommended, the use of Counter and itertools, or the solution proposed by @rahlf23 (using a for loop) ?

Comment: @djourd1: unless you need to check millions of elements hundred times per second, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long-handed approach leveraging `defaultdict()`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

some_list = [['abc', 'aa', 'xdf'], ['def', 'asd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['ghi', 'edd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', ]]

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in some_list:
    if 'abc' in i:
        if len(i)==1:
            d[None] += 1
        for j in i:
            if j=='abc': continue
            d[j] += 1
```

Yields:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'aa': 1, 'xdf': 1, 'xyz': 2, None: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your list on search criteria, then filter out the search value to get your co-occurences. Then you can use any approach to counting their frequency.

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

some_list = [['abc', 'aa', 'xdf'], ['def', 'asd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['ghi', 'edd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', ]]
search = 'abc'
co_occurrences = [[v for v in lst if v != search] if len(lst) > 1 else [None] for lst in some_list if search in lst]
print(co_occurrences)
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(co_occurrences))
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[['aa', 'xdf'], ['xyz'], ['xyz'], [None]]
Counter({'xyz': 2, 'aa': 1, 'xdf': 1, None: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

My method without importing any packages:

```
some_list = [['abc', 'aa', 'xdf'], ['def', 'asd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], 
             ['ghi', 'edd'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', ]]
d = {'None':0}
for e in some_list:
    if 'abc' in e and len(e) != 1:
        for f in e:
            if f != 'abc' and f not in d:
                d[f] = 1
            elif f != 'abc' and f in d:
                d[f] +=1
    elif 'abc' in e and len(e) == 1:
        d['None'] += 1
print(d)
```

This code will print:

```
{'None': 1, 'aa': 1, 'xdf': 1, 'xyz': 2}
```